# How do you retrieve the colour space with CImg of an image loaded with CImg?

Tags: c++, image, cimg

I am loading an image with CIMG, like so:

`CImg<unsigned char> image("lena.png");`

How do I know the e.g. four channels of that image represent RGBA colours and not CMYK? I know `CImg<>::spectrum()` gives me the amount of channels, but even the documentation says *"The meaning of the pixel values is not linked up to the number of channels (e.g. a 4-channel image may indifferently stands for a RGBA or CMYK color image)"*.

**I have searched the documentation and tutorials, but there seems to be no function to tell me the meaning of the channel data.**

So, how do I know kind of data I'm working with? Can I just assume all newly loaded image are in either RGB or RGBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is in PNG format, it is necessarily RGB or RGBA because PNG doesn't support CMYK.

If it is JPEG, I would assume it is in sRGB colourspace, but you could check with **ImageMagick** first, using:

```
identify -format "%[colorspace]" YourImage.xxx
```

---

I generated a CMYK image using **Imagemagick** and loaded it using **CImg**. It appears to perform no transformation whatsoever as a result of the colorspace and merely returns the first byte of each pixel as red (though it is cyan in reality), the second as green (though it is magenta) and so on...

I also compiled **CImg** with debugging info, with `cimg_use_jpeg` defined as `1` (so it uses `libjpeg`) and stepped through it. It *could* see in the `jpeg_info_struct` in function `_load_jpeg` that the image is CMYK, but it ignores this info - I guess you could patch `CImg` and modify a global variable quite readily to store the colourspace - if you like hacking about! Or you could request David Tschumperlé to do so via the CImg GitHub page which he does respond to...

[image]

---

Here is a possible work-around. If you don't build with `cimg_use_jpeg`, or `cimg_use_png`, or `cimg_use_tiff`, **CImg** will delegate reading files to **ImageMagick**'s command-line tool called `convert`. It will then convert your image to PNM format (in a pipe, not on disk) and **CImg** will read the data from the pipe. Crucially, **ImageMagick** always converts images being written to PNM format into sRGB colourspace, so if you have **ImageMagick** convert your images (by not using **CImg**'s built-in libraries), your images will always be read in sRGB colourspace. Essentially, **CImg** does this to read files when delegating to **ImageMagick**:

```
convert input.jpg pnm:-
```

and reads the output.

You will note that your 4-channel (previously CMYK) image suddenly becomes a 3-channel (now sRGB) image when **CImg** has delegated to **ImageMagick** because the output from **ImageMagick** is a, necessarily 3-channel, PNM file.

---

If you want to go even further...

If you set an environment variable, you can control where **CImg** looks for `convert`, so you could point it to your own *"wrapper"* around the real **ImageMagick** `convert`.

So, in concrete terms, if you do:

```
export cimg_convert_path="/Users/YourUser/bin/convertWrapper"
```

before running anything with **CImg** in it, or at the start of your program, with:

```
setenv("cimg_convert_path","/Users/YourUser/bin/convertWrapper",1);
```

**CImg** will run the following command to load your files:

```
/Users/YourUser/bin/convertWrapper input.jpg pnm:-
```

So, I am suggesting that in that wrapper file, you could modify the parameters passed to `convert` so it actually does something else:

```
convert input.jpg -auto-level pnm:-
```

So, `convertWrapper` would contain:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pick up arguments and put in array
args=( "$@" )

# Remove last argument ("pnm:-")
unset 'args[${#args[@]}-1]'

# Add our "-auto-level" parameter in before last item
args+=("-auto-level")

# Re-append "pnm:-"
args+=("pnm:-")

# Debug output to /tmp/a
echo "BEFORE: $@"         >> /tmp/a
echo "AFTER:  ${args[@]}" >> /tmp/a

# Call real "convert" with modified parameters
/usr/local/bin/magick "${args[@]}"
```

This approach means you don't need to modify **CImg**.

Comment: Right. But my software is loading arbitrary images, so I wouldn't know beforehand whether it's going to be a JPEG (sRGB) or PNG (RGB), and having to call a command line tool to figure that out seems like a band-aid, considering CImg loads the image and should know. But I'll update the question, because it doesn't clearly state I'd like to know the color space from CImg itself.

Comment: @fmw42 Fred, do you know if, in ImageMagick, output of an image as PNM causes an implicit colourspace change to RGB? I mean if the input image is say CMYK.

Comment: Ok, I checked the ImageMagick source code, and around line 1824 of `coders/pnm.c` it seems to always convert images to sRGB colourspace before writing to disk as PNM files.

Comment: Whoa, you've thoroughly updated your answer, thanks! So the conclusion is CImg in its current state doesn't store colour space. I'm probably going to request that feature on the github then, as apart from that it looks like a convenient library. We're not in the position to assume any command line tools on the users system.

Comment: I hope you get plenty of success requesting a new feature or getting the behaviour clarified from David. Please click `share` under my answer here and copy the link and paste it into anything you send CImg developers and likewise if you get a response from them please add a link here on StackOverflow to whatever you find out. Then we will all learn! Good luck! Of course, if you get a better solution, add that as an answer here and mark it as correct - I am not in the least concerned at losing any points:-)

Comment: Thanks Mark, you've been a great help! I issued a feature request here, with a reference link to this post: https://github.com/dtschump/CImg/issues/200.